# Using cross ratio to prove a theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Given $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ 4 different points of $ {\mathbb C}$, we define the cross ratio $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ as

> $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)\longrightarrow  [z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]$

As a first step, we had to show that there is an invariance of cross ratio under Möbius transformation , what I did.

I'm stuck here , how can I prove :

> $$[z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4]=\frac{(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3})}{(\frac{z_1-z_4}{z_2-z_4})}$$

And I found this following statement

> $ABC$ a triangle in complex plane & $\;P,Q,R\;$ 3 points such that :
>
> $P \in (BC)  \; , \;Q \in (CA)\;,\; R \in (AB)  $
>
> $(QR)\; $and $(BC)$ are concurrent at a point D

We have :

> $$\frac{\overline{PC}}{\overline{PB}} \, .\frac{\overline{QA}}{\overline{QC}} \, . \frac{\overline{RB}}{\overline{RA}}=[C,B,A',D]$$

How can I prove it ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: brb time to dig through my hw

Comment: You haven't given a definition of cross-ratio!!! You just wrote square brackets.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this serves as an answer, but I wanted to post these images, which I pulled straight out of my homework.

[image]

[image]

Comment: fundamentals of complex analysis by eb saff&snider, ch7-4 exercise #4

Comment: It helps  thanks a lot , no idea for the 2nd part ?